# Strange brake noise

Tags: brakes, noise

https://goo.gl/photos/8J9acXhHpqFL3nau5

My car just started making this noise when I apply the brakes. It persists for a few seconds after but only if the car is moving.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Edit: this might be the problem?

[Probable wheel](https://goo.gl/photos/Roo6wHBGZa8nB1zG8)

[Comparison](https://goo.gl/photos/9swb9sWWMcfk9z5Q6)

Comment: Interesting link.  I appears to be a horn on a steering wheel.  Was that your intent or it the incorrect image?

Comment: @DucatiKiller it's a video, really the audio is the important part.

Comment: Yes, apologies for that.   I can't really hear the sound.  OR I hear it and am not identifying the issue with it.  Can you give a time marker and description so I can listen for it?

Comment: I had the volume on my speakers all the way up and couldn't identify the noise either. Unless it's the rumbling noise around 4 seconds. You should visually inspect your brakes regardless.

Comment: Here is another one https://goo.gl/photos/3TD81uE4hr4tZGJZ8 try that. I just did it in a parking lot,  I stayed moving, then braked, then some gas and brake again.

Comment: It seems there is almost a hollow grinding sound.  Do I have that right?

Comment: @DucatiKiller yep that's a good description

Comment: Added some pictures

Comment: put in a response as a metal to metal between pad and rotor.  Hope it was helpful.  Good day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**It sounds as though your brake pads have worn down to the metal**

Brake pads are considered a consumable in the car industry, much like oil or tires.

Brake pads have material that is bound to a metal backing plate.  When that material is used up the metal backing plate can begin to grind on the disc or rotor.

Once the metal to metal contact begins a groove is worn into the rotor.

If I am correct with the sound you have worn out the brake pads and are digging into your rotor with the backing plate of the pad and are rapidly destroying the rotor.  If you get past the pad in wear you will begin to wear out the pistons in your caliper.

I suggest you replace your rotors and pads quickly if this is the case.

You can remove a front wheel and look at the pad against the rotor to confirm this theory.

best of luck.